# Ubuntu Start and End Issues

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, hard-drive, gpu

Whenever I boot Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Probook (Single Boot), The following Statements appear. They seem to be error of some sort, though my Ubuntu starts and works normally.

Another Error which appears while shutting off sometimes can be seen in the link: https://goo.gl/photos/ZCw1dBswVnq2JdNZ8

`/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: Clearing Orphaned inode 44302606 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=0)
/dev/sda1: Clearing Orphaned inode 49560530 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=17576)
/dev/sda1: Clearing Orphaned inode 49548719 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=17576)
.
.
.
.
.
/dev/sda1: clean, 299495/60530688 files, 40611432/242121216 blocks
[   46.997493] amdgpu 0000:0a:00.0: couldn't schedule ib
[   46.997546] [drm:amdgpu_sched_run_job [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Error scheduling IBs (-22)
[   46.997599] [drm:amdgpu_sched_main [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to run job!`

Please Suggest as to what can be done to remove these errors. The Ubuntu 16.04 OS feels really unstable. Following are some errors I face:
1.Once I close my screen(folding screen to touch the keyboard) while not shutting down, then when I reopen the laptop, the system hangs.
2.Ubuntu Hangs while some heavy C++ or python code runs.

Comment: Open terminal and run sudo fsck /dev/sda1. This will scan the drive for errors.

Comment: fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.